# Can you tell me a good video cources of ADO.NET?

Tags: database, ado.net, datagridview

Can you tell me a good video cources of ADO.NET, such as a work with datagridview object, data binding etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/videos.aspx

and also some good ones, depending on whether you're doing web or winforms development at

http://www.asp.net

and

http://www.windowsclient.net

use the "learn" links for those last two sites.

And if you're willing to pay a modest fee (although I don't see why you would, given the abundance of free resources) you can go here: http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/content/series/adodotnet.aspx